# Google Drive(Excel): Using Sumif for each unique string value without making a separate sumif command for each

Tags: string, excel, excel-formula, unique, sumifs

Okay, Looked for about 30 minutes before I realized that I don't have the necessary knowledge to know the proper terms to use for this question... please help... If it matters, I'm using google docs, which as best as I can tell is ALMOST always compatible with Excel.

I have a spreadsheet that has two columns that I care about, Column B contains names, and Column T contains numeric values that I need to add together depending on the name in Column B.

="Reon: " & SUMIF('Form Responses'!B2:B10000,"Reon",'Form Responses'!T2:T10000)

I could make a few hundred sumif commands like the above, and add new ones every time a new name submits the form for the first time, but this is manual and would take forever. Is there a way to get the unique values of Column B, and put them into this formula to make a list resembling:

Name1: 247, Name2: 698, Name3: 420

The Exact formatting does not really matter as long as the name is displayed with the number and not a long string of indecipherable numbers. The generated list will be read by a real live person.

Thanks for any and all help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Pnuts, Thank you for your wonderful links!

Here's the Code I used to manage it based on them.

Column One

=UNIQUE('Form Responses'!B2:B1000)

Column Two

=SUMIF('Form Responses'!B2:B100,UNIQUE('Form Responses'!B2:B100),'Form Responses'!T2:T100)

This gave me two columns with corresponding numbers and names in each. Thanks so much!